# General Q - Using a database with a website

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm new to building websites.  I have a basic front end developed, some basic jquery and css all going.  Now, I'd like to add a database in (so that my website can call, and publish data to, the database).

My choice of database was going to be MySQL.  Where I'm not sure where to go now.  Specifically:

1)  What language / method should I use to talk to the database from the website?  Or at least what options do I have? The data will end up being text, numeric and image data.   [In the past I've made the mistake of googling and stumbling upon old languages etc (ie, I started off with Bootstrap 2 for a while....)].

2)  I "develop" my website offline, and then use Amazon Web Service. I use two different computers to develop (all offline), and then publish things to AWS as a go-between / production.   If I use MySQL, how should I set it up so its easy to move it between offline and online.

I just need a point in the right direction.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Is a perfectly acceptable place to begin experimenting with databases. As Fred commented, you should either use **mysqli** or **PDO prepared statements** to insert and extract information from your database. You may also benefit from installing **phpmyadmin** (http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) so that you have a GUI for managing your database tables.

If you will be developing locally on multiple different machines, I would recommend utilizing **git** (github and bitbucket are a few to name) so that your source code can travel with you from machine to machine.

As for using your database both online and offline, phpmyadmin has a very simple import/export feature so that you can transfer your data between databases. However, it would be simpler if you stuck with just using one database, and connecting to it both locally and from your server.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I've taken a bit of a different approach.  I think I'm going to use AWS's database, simply because I'm not a database person and it sounds like they do a lot for you...  any thoughts on that?

Comment: @keynesiancross I have never used AWS's databases, however this link may be a useful resource for you in making your decision: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34525/amazon-rds-for-mysql-vs-installing-mysql-on-an-amazon-ec2-instance

Comment: Great, thanks a lot.  Man this stuff isn't easy!!